# Azure webapp denied MIME-Type

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-webapps

I'm running an Azure webapp where I will call a JSON file, but when I attempt to load the file I get a 404.17.  I've tried updating the web.config outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/media-files-http-404-azure-web-apps), but when I do that the web.config kills my site and then nothing loads at all.  The error that I get `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
         </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've also tried the following and this also brings down the site.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For your second snippet, try removing the mimeMap for .json first with <remove fileExtension=".json"/> before attempting to set it. Also, by "brings down the site", specifically what errors are you seeing?

Comment: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Comment: @RobReagan thanks!  I added that it seemed to fix the site going down, but still get the `The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler` error.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC running under Net Framework or Net Core?

Comment: @RobReagan it's .Net Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added asp.net extension and I think that resolved it for me.